# Ideal shrinking of discrete randomness source

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, random, random-functions

I have a discrete randomness source that emits random integer numbers in range `[0..N)` with uniform distribution. I need to reduce this distribution, limiting it to `[0..M)`, where `M <= N`, but keep it both integer and uniform.

I can't think of approaches that would work for `N % M != 0`. For example, for `N = 100` and `M = 99`, if projection function is `f(x) := x % M`, it appears that zero is rolled out twice more often than any other value, because both `f(0) = 0` and `f(99) = 0`. For `f(x) := floor(M * x / N)` it's the same — these methods induce aliasing, which is strictly unwanted.

Of course, I could try to select such `M'` for which `N >= M' >= M`, `N % M' == 0` and `M' % M == 0`, and just retry getting random value from source each time random value is larger than `M'`, but I don't like this approach, as it has big chance to just waste randomness.

> Is there maybe more correct solution to this problem?

What I am trying to do is distributed random number generation — I get random bitstring of fixed length `L` after collecting and processing every response, which can be seen as an integer number in range `N=2**L`, `[0..N)`. Application may not need such large numbers, it may desire random number in range `[0..M)`, so I need to somehow truncate what I have to what I need, and that's what this question is about.

Comment: How precious is randomness here? The usual solution involves throwing away plenty of randomness, since it's considered easy to get more. If you don't want to waste a single bit, you could do something kind of like [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding). Treat the infinite sequence of random bits as specifying a single point uniformly drawn from the interval $[0, 1]$, then every time you need to draw a number from $0$ to some $M$, figure out which of $M$ equally-sized subintervals the point is in and zoom in on that subinterval for future draws.